Place bounty on another user's old question or re-ask?
I have the same question as Separable polynomial mod $\mathfrak{p}$, which was asked in 2013 and is unanswered. Should I reask it myself (and link them, of course), or place a bounty on the existing question?
Arguments for placing bounty:

The question already exists, so re-asking would make them duplicates.
It is well enough written, albeit on the shorter side.

Arguments for re-asking:

The user has not been active since 2015, and the question has never seen activity except for the occasional vote.
If I re-asked, I would add examples and my attempts to the question. I would not feel comfortable adding this in an edit on the other user's question, but perhaps it could be done in a comment while placing the bounty.

I would prefer re-asking, since it seems the simpler and natural approach to me. But I'm unsure if it's frowned upon.
EDIT: I have now re-asked the question (see Does minimal polynomial being separable mod $\mathfrak p$ imply that $p$ does not divide $\left|\mathcal O_L / \mathcal O_K[\alpha]\right|$?) since I believe I have added significantly to the context and discussion. If I get an answer, I will mark the old question as a duplicate.

If this is a duplicate on Meta, I apologize, but I couldn't find a corresponding question, although I imagine it would have been asked before

I'm inclined to say you should put a bounty on the existing question.

@Shaun Alright, and then add my additional context/progress as comment(s)? Or is it preferred to add a significant extra paragraph as an edit?

This is related. You have new context to give to an old question, but it doesn't have any good answers or other quality that we need to worry about salvaging. Write a new, better written question, and the old one will end up being closed as a duplicate of the new.

Also I'm interested in the topic so if yours doesn't get answered in a while, ping me and I'll bounty it for you myself

Thank you both for your guidance. After deliberation, I decided to re-ask the question, since I believe I have added significantly to the context and discussion. If I get an answer, I will mark the old question as a duplicate.

A related discussion from 2012: How to grab users' attention on an old question? (The site probaly changed a bit since then.)

@AlexanderGruber You mentioned you have an interest in the subject. I wonder if you're able to shed some light on the current answer, which somewhat goes over my head? (Sorry, I don't know any other way to get in touch).

I would put a bounty on the existing question. However, this does not guarantee that the question will get answered.
One alternative approach we have experimented with on Literature Stack Exchange is a meta post titled List of bounties with no deadline. Answers to this question list question with the bounty that would be awarded to the answer that meets your requirements. The downside to this approach is that a moderator needs to add the featured tag to it for the post to become visible.
